Can you write the equation of oscillating electric field for a stream of photons given the equation of the whole beam?
The electric field oscillation of a beam of light is given by: $$ E = E_o \sin(kx-2\pi ft) $$
Energy of every photon in this case would be $E_p = hf$ since the frequency of oscillation is $f$.
By equating the total intensity of light in terms of the electric field and in terms of energies of indivisual photons, we can find the number of photons crossing a unit area per unit time. Let this number be $n_p$.
I wanted to ask if I can consider the whole beam of light to be composed of indivisual beams with each beam having one photon per unit time per unit area and also them being in the same phase. If I can, then the the maximum electric field oscillation of each such beam should be $\frac{E_o}{n_p}$.

In reality for all laser beams the beam shape is Gaussian  (a normal distribution). It does not make sense to have a "maximum oscillation" because photons behave individually.  Photons are always created one at a time and always absorbed one at a time due to the resonance frequency of the electron in the atom/molecule.

It's also impossible to make photons in phase one at a time .... when making single photons the excited atom or molecule will release the photon at random normally distributed very short times.

@PhysicsDave So that means I can't create two beams composed of just a single stream of photons and superimpose them to get another beam whose equation can be known with certainity?

There is a concept called "etendue". Some of its implications are if you have 2 beams of the same wavelength (exact color) and polarization there is no way to mix them (i.e. mirrors, beam splitters, prisms, filters etc) it is impossible. If you rotate one beam then you can do polarization combining but your resultant beam is no longer perfect polarized.  (you can use dichroic filters to combine beams of different wavelengths also).  You can shine 2 flashlights (or lasers on the same spot but that is not beam combining as the beams would continue to separate if they were to travel further.

In the case of radio waves we have many photons kind of acting as one .... but they act on electrons in the antenna one at a time.

@PhysicsDave I see. So basically I can't superimpose two waves if they have same polarization and frequeny. Lol, I forgot to consider polarization in my derivation. Oscillations due to non polarized light can't be added like scalars anyway, so my derivation automatically breaks down. Thanks for your reply.

No problem. If you have time read my answers on the double slit experiment… Feynman, modes, EM field …. I think it would be interesting for you.

I will surely read them whenever I get the time.

You can’t consider the whole beam of light to be composed of individual beams with each beam having one photon per unit time per unit area. Here is the answer, why not. A bit more general about EM radiation, EM waves and photons.
